# Select all elements using getElementsByClassName in a function, not working

Tags: javascript

I have a simple "fade out text on scroll" effect using Javascript.

Here's a working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4opjh5ef/1/

I wanted to let the effect applied to all elements with the class `fade`. However, trying to loop it inside the function doesn't seem to work.

Here is the not working code:

```js
var fadeOut = document.getElementsByClassName('fade');
var fadeOutParent = fadeOut.parentElement.scrollHeight;


function scrolled() {

    for (var i = 0; i < fadeOut.length; i++) {
       fadeOut[i].style.opacity = 1-((window.pageYOffset)/(fadeOutParent/2));
    }

}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolled);
```

Any idea?

Comment: There's a potential "divide by zero" if fadeOutParent evaluates to Zero....

Comment: I have a few questions, where is your JavaScript, is it inside of a ready/load event, at the end of the body or in the head? In other words, have your elements finished loading before you tried to do this? Also, is your CSS `transition` property commented out in your project, like in the fiddle?

Comment: @NeilMoss I'm sorry, do you mind to explain? I meant to use `fadeOutParent` only to get the parent's height, since in my case the parent(s) will always have a a certain height.

Comment: @LogicalBranch in the bottom of the body; all elements loaded; CSS are also properly commented. Except for the JS, it's exactly the same. Here's a not working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0jnLdh31/

Comment: @deathlock I think I may have found [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55791104/10415695), you've been trying to select the `parentElement` of a `NodeList`, which isn't possible, you need to be selecting the `parentElement` of each child in the loop.

Comment: If parents _always_ have a non-zero height, then you're OK, but the code will go bang if that assumption no longer holds true if _something_ sets the height of a parent element to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you're trying to select the `parentElement` of a `NodeList`, which isn't possible.

Here, try moving the `fadeOutParent` variable into the `for` loop instead:

```
var fadeOut = document.getElementsByClassName("fade");
function scrolled() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fadeOut.length; i++) {
    var fadeOutParent = fadeOut[i].parentElement.scrollHeight;
    fadeOut[i].style.opacity = 1 - ((window.pageYOffset) / (fadeOutParent / 2));
  }
}
window.addEventListener("scroll", scrolled);
```

Good luck.

Comment: Got it, thanks! Two answers posted at the same time but I chose to vote this one. If I can choose both then I'd chose it. Thank you for your answers, both!

Comment: @MaheerAli I have never spammed any post on this site, you can check my history and see for yourself. I didn't copy your code, I've tested and corrected my final solution in a local browser page. Also, I have no reason to *"prove to you"* that there's a difference between our two answers but there is a difference in how we explained what the problem was and how we came to the solution. If you're offended, then I apologise as that was not my intent but I hope you understand that just because our code is similar, it doesn't mean that I haven't put effort into answering this question.

Comment: @MaheerAli It's OK, I haven't taken any offence to anything you've said and to be fair I understand where you're coming from, there has been quite a lot of spam & duplicate content on this site lately.

Answer (score 1):

You should have different `fadeOutParent` for each element because each element have different parent. You should assign `fadeOutParent` inside the loop

```js
var fadeOut = document.getElementsByClassName('fade');
function scrolled() {
  for (var i = 0; i < fadeOut.length; i++) {
        var fadeOutParent = fadeOut[i].parentElement.scrollHeight;
       fadeOut[i].style.opacity = (1-((window.pageYOffset)/(fadeOutParent/2)))
    }
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', scrolled);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 1000px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #333;
}

.content {
  padding: 10%;
}

p {
  line-height: 1.75;
}

.top {
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #aaa;
  height: 300px;
  opacity: 1;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'helvetica';
  color: #fff;
}

.title {
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 700;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60%;
  left: 100px;
  /* gak perlu, udah cukup smooth
  transition: opacity 0.5s ease;
  */
}
.span {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 300;
  position: absolute;
  top: 77%;
  right: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="top" id="top">
    <div class="title fade" id="title">
      Fade Away
    </div>
    <div class="span fade">
      Subtitle
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="content">
    <p>
      What's scrolling is actually .content, not body.
    </p>
    <p>
      White paper segmentation families granular big data dynamic natural resources energize, vibrant families social return on investment human-centered radical. Inclusive philanthropy design thinking agile, we must stand up ecosystem; support social impact
      efficient game-changer ecosystem and correlation shared value. Ideate state of play technology circular, disrupt innovation paradigm movements change-makers. Natural resources triple bottom line bandwidth movements venture philanthropy incubator
      energize effective problem-solvers uplift. Greenwashing we must stand up segmentation, program area; resilient venture philanthropy, academic expose the truth entrepreneur activate transparent venture philanthropy empower communities deep dive.
      NGO collective impact synergy initiative, bandwidth, storytelling revolutionary inspiring, our work segmentation.
    </p>
    <p>
      Deep dive the resistance, problem-solvers impact investing social entrepreneur indicators inspiring energize. Boots on the ground our work systems thinking think tank innovation. Green space catalyze blended value sustainable empower communities thought
      partnership.

    </p>
    <p>
      NGO disrupt, expose the truth save the world, black lives matter challenges and opportunities thought leader movements efficient theory of change cultivate activate strategy LGBTQ+. Paradigm; emerging because, a; social enterprise strategy accessibility.
      Design thinking, segmentation; relief, justice her body her rights gender rights. Catalyze parse inclusion thought leader, overcome injustice, expose the truth collective impact silo ideate.

    </p>
    <p>
      Transparent benefit corporation social impact data families scale and impact social capital a shared unit of analysis. Uplift dynamic; movements, co-creation, co-create, expose the truth segmentation data technology collaborate, academic cultivate collective
      impact accessibility. Benefit corporation theory of change, entrepreneur venture philanthropy move the needle, indicators, segmentation co-creation revolutionary revolutionary co-create deep dive gender rights. NGO initiative; vibrant; our work
      inspire; inspire communities, rubric, gender rights collaborate gender rights data deep dive.

    </p>
    <p>
      To innovate outcomes justice benefit corporation, policymaker impact investing. Equal opportunity green space empower communities strategy, co-create compelling, gender rights shared vocabulary shared value transparent. Uplift, NGO resist, vibrant, mass
      incarceration collaborative cities vibrant and. Shared vocabulary paradigm, boots on the ground program areas change-makers, corporate social responsibility data strategy because replicable expose the truth human-centered. Program area storytelling
      social innovation preliminary thinking social innovation storytelling correlation. Then; ecosystem granular impact impact expose the truth outcomes but entrepreneur movements.
    </p>

  </div>

</div>
```

I would suggest you to use `querySelectorAll()` instead of `getElementsByClass()`